# How to organise mysql volumes for different projects with different mysqld versions in docker-compose file?

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

Usually, I create a folder with a name 'docker' inside my project directory so I can use different configurations for different projects. I put all docker files in this folder. 
I've created this docker-compose file to work with a project that uses MySQL v5.5.:

```html
version: "3"
services:
    mysql:
        image: mysql:5.5
        ports:
          - 13307:3306
        environment:
          - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123
        volumes:
          - mysqldata:/var/lib/mysql
        container_name: mysql

volumes:
  mysqldata:
    driver: "local"
```

Now I need to create another project that uses MySQL v.5.6
So how should look the same file for this project? Especially volumes, service name and container name. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple services and volumes in one compose YAML definition. Like this:

`version: "3"
services:
    mysql-v1:
        image: mysql:5.5
        ports:
          - 13307:3306
        environment:
          - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123
        volumes:
          - mysqldata-v1:/var/lib/mysql
        container_name: mysql-v1
    mysql-v2:
        image: mysql:5.6
        ports:
          - 13308:3306
        environment:
          - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123
        volumes:
          - mysqldata-v2:/var/lib/mysql
        container_name: mysql-v2
volumes:
  mysqldata-v1:
    driver: "local"
  mysqldata-v2:
    driver: "local"`

You configure image, container name and volume to your liking in such way.

Another approach would be to use env vars as parameters. You can configure the compose in such a way:

`version: "3"
services:
    mysql:
        image: mysql:5.5
        ports:
          - ${port}:3306
        environment:
          - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123
        volumes:
          - mysqldata:/var/lib/mysql
        container_name: mysql-port-${port}
volumes:
  mysqldata:
    driver: "local"`

Then all you need to do is "export port=2222" for example to set the port to 2222 and then use the compose. This will set both the port and the name of the container to to mysql-port-2222.

Comment: thank you, but I mean I need to use a different docker-compose.yml file for a different project

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You can put the 2nd service and volume in a different file if that's what you need. Or do you need to have 1 file that is configure-able with parameters? If so you can pass env vars to the compose - see here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/